# How to add more ticks to D3 timeline charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I have a stacked time line chart, but I am unable to include more ticks in the chart.

I've tried this code:

```
var chart = d3.timeline().showAxisTop().stack().background('#C0C0C0').orient('top')
   .relativeTime()
   //.absoluteTime()
   .tickFormat({
      format: function(d) {
         displayDate.setHours(hours++);
         return formatter(displayDate);
      },
      tickTime: d3.time.hours,
      ticks: 20,
      tickInterval: 1,
      tickSize: 30,
   });
chart.margin({
   left: 120,
   right: 0,
   top: 50,
   bottom: 0
});
chart.labelMargin(25);
var svg = d3.select("#timelineAxisTop").append("svg").attr("width", width)
   .datum(testData).call(chart)
   .selectAll("text").attr("class", "timeLineFont");
// $('.tick timeLineFont').attr("x", 75).attr("y", -12);
$('.tick').find('text').attr('x', 85).attr('y', -12);
};
```

[chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVbOd.png)

Answer (score 0):

As per the image shown in your question your interval is 1 hour for each tick so better change:

`ticks : 20`  to `ticks : (d3.time.hour,1)` by eliminating `tickInterval` and if you still want more ticks then change your ticks appropriately may be `ticks : (d3.time.mintues,45)` for example

Comment: I tried as you said, but it is not working. Even when I send dynamic data, the scale is reduced to two values showing  only (07:00). How can I fix the x-axis scale with fixed time interval scale. @ SiddP

Comment: Can you share a fiddle then it would be easy for me to help you out

Comment: Here is the reference I have used https://github.com/jiahuang/d3-timeline/blob/master/examples/example.html

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it did not work in my case.Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated. @Siddp